# Rails - storing multiple value in database using checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I am having a model **investor_profile.rb**

I am having a field where he/she can choose various options(acquiring a business, lending to a business,...) in checkbox. Form code below.

```
<%= form_with model: @investor_profile do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :interested_in %>
      <% interests.each do |activity| %>
        <%= f.check_box :interested_in, { multiple: true }, activity, nil %>
       <% end %>
      <%= f.submit %>
<%= end %>
```

How can i design a database for storing multiple values? If it is a single value i can store it in **interested_in** column in **investor_profile** table.

Comment: Could you add the 2 models you want to join?

Comment: @LolWalid Can i use a third model called **investor_interests** and add list of values to it? like i can access it via **user.investor_profiles.first.interested_in** will return a list of selected interests?

Comment: That's the idea , i m posting my answer. You need to add a join_table ! (my response is with User And Intereset table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to save several interests on your each investor_profiles record.

You have to create third model investor_interests, where you will have all of the interest options. 
You also need connection table called for example investor_profile_interests, which will belong to both, investor interests and investor profiles. In the investor_profile_interests table you will have investor_profile_id and investor_interest_id.

```
So that:
InvestorProfile has many InvestorProfileInterest
InvestorProfileInterest belongs to InvestorProfile
InvestorProfileInterest belongs to InvestorInterest
```

In this case you will have many to many relationship with investor_interests and will be able to store several interests on each profile.

connection table will look like following:

```
**investor_profile_id**  **investor_interest_id**    
-----------------------------------------------------
        1                        1
        1                        2
        1                        3
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a join table between your User and Interest models

You want to have something like this

```
users table
id
1
2
3

interests table 
id name
1 "interest 1"
2 "interest 2"
3 "interest 3"

interest_users table (the join table)
id interest_id user_id
1  1           1        # User 1 is interesed in interest 1
1  2           1        # User 1 is interesed in interest 2
1  3           1        # User 1 is interesed in interest 3
1  3           2        # User 2 is interesed in interest 3

User 3 is interesed in nothing!
```

Let's do it with rails

First create the join_table through a migration, [create_join_table rails documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_join_table)

```
# db/create_join_table_user_interest.rb
class CreateJoinTableUserInterest < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_join_table :user, :interest do |t|
      t.index %i[user_ud interest_id]
      t.index %i[interest_id user_ud]
    end
  end
end
```

Then create the joining model `InterestUser`, each row of the joining model belongs to both table!

```
# models/user_interest.rb
class InterestUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :interest
end
```

Update your models to tell it, it has interests (look at the [rails through tutorial](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) )

```
# model/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_interests
  has_many :interests, through: :user_interest
end

# model/interest.rb
class Interest < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_interests
  has_many :user, through: :user_interest
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When submitting your form, `params["investor_profile"]["interested_in"]` will return an array of string from `interests` in your controller.

That is why the simplest solution using the rails way is to store this value in a text column `interested_in` in your `investor_profiles` table.

Just add the following code in your model to [serialize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize) the array.

```
class InvestorProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :interested_in, Array
end
```

Then you can save easily the params without formatting.

I made the assumption `interests` is only a list of tag and that you don't have `interests` table.

The limit of the serialization is that you cannot use efficient SQL query to filter investor_profiles on their interests.